# PyTorch: new_ones vs ones

Tags: pytorch

In PyTorch what is the difference between `new_ones()` vs `ones()`. For example,

```
x2.new_ones(3,2, dtype=torch.double)
```

vs

```
torch.ones(3,2, dtype=torch.double)
```

Comment: What is your variable `x2` in this instance?

Answer (score 28):

For the sake of this answer, I am assuming that your `x2` is a previously defined `torch.Tensor`. If we then head over to the [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.new_ones), we can read the following on `new_ones()`:

> Returns a Tensor of size `size` filled with `1`. By default, the
>   returned Tensor has the same `torch.dtype` and `torch.device` as this
>   tensor.

Whereas [`ones()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.ones)

> Returns a tensor filled with the scalar value 1, with the shape
>   defined by the variable argument sizes.

So, essentially, `new_ones` allows you to quickly create a new `torch.Tensor` on the same device and data type as a *previously existing* tensor (with ones), whereas `ones()` serves the purpose of creating a `torch.Tensor` from scratch (filled with ones).

Comment: What are the benefits of this? When would I use one instead of the other?

Comment: `new_ones()` can be used on an existing tensor, like `x = torch.tensor(); x.new_ones([2,3])`. This allows you to move your tensor `x` freely across devices or compute the dimensions, *before* actually initializing it. `ones()`, on the other hand, *directly* creates a new tensor: `x = torch.ones([2,3])`.

Answer (score 6):

> new_ones()

```
# defining the tensor along with device to run on. (Assuming CUDA hardware is available)

x = torch.rand(5, 3, device="cuda")
```

`new_ones()` works with existing tensor. `y` will inherit the `datatype` from `x` and it will run on same `device` as defined in `x`

```
y = x.new_ones(2, 2)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]], device='cuda:0')
```

> ones()

```
# defining tensor. By default it will run on CPU.
x = torch.ones(5, 3)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])
```

`ones()` is used to define tensor with `1.` (as shown in example) of given `size` and is not dependent on the existing tensor, whereas `new_ones()` works with existing tensor which inherits properties like `datatype` and `device` from existing tensor and define the `tensor` with given `size`.